# Update Google Maps marker with long polling without blocking UI

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-maps-markers

I have a Google Map (MapFragment) with more than 5 markers on it. I want to update the position of markers for every 10-15 seconds. I will be getting new co ordinates via a API call.

Is there any way we can update the markers without blocking the UI? Sample C# snippet for long polling would be awesome..

I tried doing -

```
    RunOnUiThread(() =>
    {
        while(true){
          //UPDATE MARKERS HERE
          Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
```

but it freeze the UI. Is there any way to update markers without freezing UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing:

```
RunOnUiThread(() =>
{
    while(true){
      //UPDATE MARKERS HERE
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Forces everything inside of the anonymous method to run on the UI thread. So the while loop inclusive of the `Thread.Sleep` is blocking the UI.

Instead you want to do your long operation asynchronously, for instance using TPL (async/await) in C#.

```
Dictionary<int, Marker> _markers = new Dictionary<int, Marker>();

async Task PollServerAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var coordinates = await GetNewCoordinatesFromServerAsync(cancellationToken);

        foreach (var coord in coordinates)
        {
            var marker = _markers[_coord.Id];
            RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                marker.SetPosition(coord.Position);    
            });
        }

        await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```